# How to update ngModel using jquery in angular 6?

Tags: jquery, angular6

I want to update value of ngModel on click of a button using javascript. I have tried but it's not working.

index.html

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<my-app>loading</my-app>
<script>

    $scope.$apply(function() { 
   // every changes goes here
      $('#t').val('new '); 
    });

</script>
```

app.component.html

```
{{ name }}
<p>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" id="t">
</p>
<button type="button" onclick="test()">Clicx</button>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
}
```

Comment: define a public name: any; in your component.ts and initialize the model inside the function which executes "onClick"

Comment: can you please explain it with code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Declare var $: any to use JQuery anywhere.

app.component.html

```
{{ name }}
<p>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" id="t">
</p>
<button type="button" (click)="test()">Clicx</button>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
declare var $: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  test() {
    $("#t").val("Test Value");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To populate your model you need to define it in your component.ts file

```
declare var jquery: any;
declare var $: any;

export class AppComponent  {

  public name: any; //define your model 

  test(val){
      this.name = val;
  }
}
```

Comment: like : $('button').click(function(){
    $('#t').val('krr');
  })

Comment: After you've declared var $: any, you can use jQuery anywhere on your component.ts

Comment: You are the best judge. Mark answer that solves your issue.